# Haskell - output a type which takes 2 parametes

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make an array of my own type `letterCount` in form of [('letter',occurance),(),...]. How can I make an output of a type which takes 2 parameters. Here's my code:

```
type LetterCount = (Char,Int)

 letterOccur :: Char->[Char] -> Int
 letterOccur c [] = 0
 letterOccur c (x:xs) = if (c == x) then ((letterOccur c xs) + 1)
                          else letterOccur c xs

 letterStats :: [Char] -> [LetterCount]
 letterStats :: [] = []
 letterStats (x:xs) = [x,(letterOccur x (x:xs))] ++ letterStats xs
```

Comment: `map (head &&& length) . group . sort`

Comment: @karakfa Arrows might not be the best concept to throw at beginners.

Comment: OK then, replace with `\x -> (head x, length x)`

Comment: Hint: `x,(letterOccur x (x:xs))` doesn't define a tuple in Haskell.  It does in OCaml though.

Comment: This looks like it's a typo. Just do `[(x, letterOccur x (x:xs))]`.

Comment: @Rhymoid: right, who would [_throw_ an arrow](http://1.droppdf.com/files/rlXDU/what-if-randall-munroe.pdf#page=1362&zoom=auto,0,331.2536)? ...seriously though, I'd argue that makes perfect sense to teach beginners about `&&&` and `***`, though perhaps only with the simplified signature `(a->b) -> (a->c) -> a->(b,c)`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout That reminds me of an answer in which I didn't use `(&&&)` for fear of confusing a beginner, only to end up using `liftA2 (,)` instead :) (Nowadays I agree with you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to do something like **this**:

```
letterStats :: [Char] -> [LetterCount]
letterStats :: [] = []
letterStats (x:xs) = (x, (+1) $ letterOccur x xs) : letterStats xs
```

All you want to do is **add +1** as you are not counting x when checking xs for all x occurances. Also what you want is to return a list of **the letterCount type** which **is a Tuple** not a list, therefore I changed

```
[x, letterOccur x xs] ++ letterStats xs
```

to

```
(x, (+1) $ letterOccur x xs) : letterStats xs
```

Although you could also do this:

```
[(x, (+1) $ letterOccur x xs)] ++ letterStats xs
```

But is unnecessary.